# How to implement radio buttons for specific scenario in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button

I've searched around but haven't found an answer, but I'm also not sure what terms to search for, so please point me to similar questions if you know of any.

**Scenario**: I have posts.  I have an admin side and a public side.  I want a single post displayed on the public side front page.

On the admin side, on the posts index page, I would like to be able to select a radio button next to the post I want displayed on the front page.  My guess is I would need a form, radio buttons for each of the posts, and an update button.  But that's as far as I'm able to get on my own.

I've looked into virtual attributes, but I don't think that's what I need, or is it?  What's a good way to accomplish what I need?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a "public" field to your posts model, and access it via a checkbox on the edit post form. In your controller on a create or update, check to see if the public field is true, if so then you'll need to run something like Post.update_all(['public = ?', false], ['id != ?', current_post_id]) in order to revert any existing public posts back to private.

Alternatively, you could create a simple model for AppData (:id => :integer, :key => :string, :value => :string) and store the id of the currently selected public post on a row in that table. To keep it simple, you'll want to serialize the :value field in your model. In this case, you would use just an unattached checkbox_tag in your view and capture that value from the params hash. If it's checked, then you'll need to update the AppData row with the new id.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I'll try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: If it doesn't, let me know what problems you have and I'll update the answer to fit.

Comment: I ended up going the second route you suggested above.  Thanks for your help.